# chess tournament

Tags: combinatorics

$n$ players participate at a chess tournament (single round-robin). Players are granted one point (1) for a win, a half (½) point for a draw, and no points (0) for a loss. There are a total of 
$$\frac12 n (n-1)$$
points. At the end, there is the following situation

- a winner ($w$ points)
- a second-placed ($s$ points)
- the other $n-2$ have the same score ($d$ points).

and $w>s>d$. Of course
$$\frac12 n (n-1) = w + s + (n-2)d$$
How many participants can obtain this result?

Comment: I edited your question, please check that I didn't change its content. However, I do not understand your question. Are you asking for the total number of different configurations with the given restrictions??

Comment: Or maybe the set of possibles $n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreach $n \geqslant 3$, there is a solution :

- when two d-players play against, there is a draw
- when a d-player play against the s-player, the s-player win
- when a d-player play against the w-player, the w-player win
- when the s-player play against the w-player, the w-player win

Comment: I would like to know the set of possibles n.

Comment: As I've said, the possibles $n$ are the $n$ who are larger than $3$.

Comment: You are right. There is a solution for every n >= 3.

Comment: Now, please consider the tournament in which w + s = 8. Is there only one n or a set?

Comment: @Goofy: Ask a separate question.