# Chess tournament with restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics

$n$ players participate at a chess tournament (single round-robin).
Players are granted one point (1) for a win, a half (1/2) point for a draw, and no points (0) for a loss. There are a total of $$\frac12 n (n-1)$$ points.
At the end the is the following situation:

- a winner ($w $ points)
- a second-placed ($s$ points)
- the other $n-2$ have the same score ($d$ points)
- $w + s = 8$

> Question: What are the possible values of $n$?

Comment: ([Related earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/468870/))

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question? What equations / inequalities can you write down? For example, can there be 20 players?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the earlier, as the total score of the top two is now specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $w+s=8$ and $w \gt s, s \le 3\frac 12$ so $d$ is at most $3.$  We can write the total score $8+d(n-2)=\frac 12n(n-1)$ and solve the quadratic to get $n=\frac 12(2d+1 \pm \sqrt{4d^2-12d+65})$  As the square root is not integral for any $d \le 3$, there is no solution.

Another way to see it is that we must have $n$ at least $5$, so there are more than $8$ total points.  If $n=5$ we would have $10$ total points.  With $n-2=3,$ we would have to have $d=\frac 23$, which is not allowed.  If $n=6$, there are $15$ total points, so $d=\frac 74$.  If $n=7,$ there are $21$ total points and $d=\frac {13}8$. You can continue, but $d$ never comes out half-integral.

Comment: I found the tournament with n=16. Point are, total, 120; players "d" are 16 - 2 = 14; each with (120-8)/14 = 8.

Comment: Conclusion: there are two n for w+s=8. n=9, points=36, d players=7 each with 4 points; n=16, points=120, d players=14 each with 8 points

Comment: But in both those cases $d$ is not less than $s$, so the second place player is not in second place.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I didn't check, sorry. It is confirmed that there is no solution !!